# PHP: Check if string has format of a numbered list

Tags: php, regex

I want to check if a string has the format of a numbered list to format this lines correctly:

```
1. Something
Text
1.1. Anything
Text
```

Should get

```
<h2>1. Something</h2>
Text
<h3>1.1. Anything</h3>
Text
```

And so on...

I tried something like this for a preg_match:

```
#([\d]*\.)*\s*\K(.+?)$#s
```

Comment: you need to use preg_replace not preg_match. Why the first numbered text was included within <h2> and the second within <h3>?

Comment: The article-title itself has <h1>, so the content will be <h2> and <h3>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str = "1. Something\nText\n1.1. Anything\nText"; 

$result = preg_replace_callback('/^\d+\.((?:\d+\.)*)\h+.+$/m', 
          function($m) {$t=($m[1]!="")?'h3':'h2'; return "<$t>$m[0]</$t>";}, $str);
```

**Output:**

```
<h2>1. Something</h2>
Text
<h3>1.1. Anything</h3>
Text
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nF3uD1/2)

Comment: For deeper level I need 'higher' heading-format. 1. should get <h2> 1.1. should get <h3>.